# adding scale bar to plotly.express map

Tags: python, plotly

Is it possible to add a scale bar (for distances) and maybe a north arrow to a plotly.express.choropleth_mapbox map? I was not able to do so.

Comment: Maybe: http://dash-leaflet.herokuapp.com/ can help you.

Comment: Your question is not clear, could you please provide a small example for what you are intending to do?

Comment: What is the purpose of the scale bar?

Comment: It's not my question so can't add a figure. As stated, a scale bar displays **distance**. So including a scale bar will give the viewer a relative measure of distance between objects

Comment: Looks like something that may not be available yet https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/5295

Comment: Some example: https://www.exprodat.com/blogs/when-scale-bars-dont-scale/